# The system-wide Stack Exchange inbox is empty

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-exchange, global-inbox

Today, when I get a new mail indicator on the Stack Exchange link and click on it, the inbox doesn't display anything. I can check the sites individually by going to them and I see that there are indeed comments addressed to me.

It's also not showing older comments.

This was working yesterday.

I'm in Chrome on Vista.

Comment: +1. Mine is broken as well. Chrome on Mac.

Comment: Mine was also suddenly emptied, and now seems to be showing only the one comment made to me after 14:00 UTC (but it shows that one no matter which site I'm on.)

Comment: +1.5 Safari on Mac. Not working on V-Tech Talking Whiz Kid Mouse PRO Deluxe either.

Comment: +1 Firefox on Mac. Hopefully it is not `-bydesign`.

Comment: Now I'm starting to get new messages. Strangely enough it's never worked on a VIC-20. ;)

Comment: I am getting comments only from the new SE sites but not SO. Huh?

Comment: +1. FireFox 3.6 on Windows Xp and Windows 7, Chrome on Windows 7. Empty inbox, whatever the site I invoke the inbox in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like we had a back-end blip late last night that broke inbox loading.

Basically, if we haven't seen you for awhile we drop your inbox (persisting it of course).  The next time we see you, we start the process of loading your inbox.  This can take a few minutes (though is often much faster).  This loading part stopped working.

So far as I can tell, there was no data loss.  Additionally, you would still have been notified of any *new* activity (as it would go into your "empty" inbox immediately, independent of the loading process).

Anyway, the process has been restored and everybody's inboxes should start being reloaded now.