# My inbox items have been deleted

Tags: bug, status-completed, global-inbox

> #### Related:
>
> - [The system-wide Stack Exchange inbox is empty](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66337/the-system-wide-stack-exchange-inbox-is-empty)
> - [The SO global inbox is empty sometimes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67498/the-so-global-inbox-is-empty-sometimes)

I had a notification of a new inbox message (cleared now), but I can't see any items when I open it.

[image: screenshot]

Also, `http://stackexchange.com/inbox/genuwine` just responds with an empty array:

```
[]
```

#### Update

I now have **one** item in my global inbox: The comments that have been left on this question.

Comment: What's that big Questions-thingy?!

Comment: @UristMcBobby: Nevermind the Questions-thingy. It's a user script.

Comment: That's odd.  I have items in my inbox, so it must not be affecting everyone (yet...)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Can we install memory in every ‪#stackoverflow‬ web server without you noticing? let's find out.](https://twitter.com/Nick_Craver/status/216183163448328193)

Hmmm I guess not.

I gracefully brought web server 7 out of rotation all nice and proper (this is needed because the internal API backends used for the inbox in places need them, and they're unchecked in HAProxy).  *Then* I not-so-gracefully shut down web server 6 instead of 7, woops.

I purged your inbox cache, it'll return to normal for anyone else this happened to as their cache expires.

Comment: It's working now. Thanks. Is there a guinea pig badge for this? :-P

Comment: @Dennis - the hacker badge! which may or may not exist, and may or may not have been awarded

Comment: `Then I not-so-gracefully shut down web server 6` You did pull the wrong plug, did you?

Comment: @UristMcBobby - no, that's insulting! It was the wrong shutdown button and 2 confirmation prompts, I'm *way* more incompetent than just yanking the cord, I *confirmed* I'm incompetent, twice.